# Trying to generate a task with specific details and attachments on microsoft planner utilizing powerautomate

Tags: json, workflow, power-automate, microsoft-planner, microsoft-forms

I am trying to generate a power automate cloud flow that gets response details from a microsoft form and I keep running into issues when trying to update and old flow that used to work but as soon as it transitioned into the new designer now my JSON does not work as intended. I am not versed enough perhaps and it may be a simple issue however I can't get around the issues. My microsoft form has different types of data however my form question 8 is an object, it is a file upload that stems from a sharepoint link where users download a copy, edit the fields they need to and reupload it utilizing form question 8.
I need my form questions (responses) once submitted, need to create and update a microsoft planner task detail. My file upload needs to be added as an attachment to the task and I'm having too many issues when trying to just use the dynamic expressions thus I reverted to using an older flow structure with JSON per a friends recommendation. Does anyone know what would be the best use case of actions or steps to take in order to perform the automated cloud task I need? I have very basic coding knowledge so I am trying to shy away from anything too complicated.

I tried using my action steps to perform what I need and my flow works, it creates my task with my desired task name, its just the details that are not updating properly. My current steps (with json)

1. When a new form is submitted.
2. Get reponse details
3. Compose
4. Initialize Variable
5. Parse JSON
6. Apply to each (Create a task)
   6b. Update task details

Comment: Question is too generic, update it with the parts your are stuck at, share what you've done/tried, where flow is failing etc...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.